# How to fix this R error (when installing package Rcmdr)?

Tags: r, r-commander

Does anyone know how to fix this Rcmdr error? Rcmdr is a package in R that enables you to do statistical analysis in R without actually knowing how to code in R. I think this is from a MAC computer. I'm trying to help a student fix this over email, but I'm actually new to Rcmdr and MAC stuff (I've used PC's all my life).

An image of the error is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ugmeui5xfpahhu/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-28%20at%208.45.08%20PM.jpg

Thanks a lot for your time/help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's left over install errors from the student's previous R session. Get your student to open R in a different directory (so .Rapp.history isn't restored), and try to run `install.packages("Rcmdr", dependencies=TRUE)` again.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am getting the same error.